# Trouble With Collisions On Swift SpriteKIT XCODE

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am currently making a game where there is a big person running and a small person running, and my game requires it to detect and end the game when they collide, however it is not working for some reason and does not detect.  I used a println to tell me when it does, and it is doing nothing and they just run right past each other.  Here is my code that I have used for it.  Thank you for your time!  Could you please let me know if I am doing anything wrong?

Thanks

**Here Is The Code TO My DidMoveToView:**

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    BigPerson.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    BigPerson.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0





    self.hitagain = true
    self.respawn = false

    self.ChooseRandomScene()


    scoreLabelNode.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
    scoreLabelNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.frame.size.height / 1.26)
    scoreLabelNode.fontSize = 125
    scoreLabelNode.alpha = 0
    scoreLabelNode.zPosition = 9
    scoreLabelNode.text = "\(ScoreNumber)"
    self.addChild(scoreLabelNode)

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self


    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake( 0.0, -10.0 )

    var groundimage = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ground")
    groundimage.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Linear
    var groundbody = SKTexture(imageNamed: "floorbody")
    var titleimage = SKTexture(imageNamed: "title1")
    var playbuttonimage = SKTexture(imageNamed: "play")
    playbuttonimage.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Linear
    var leaderboardimage = SKTexture(imageNamed: "leaderboardbox")
    leaderboardimage.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Linear

    var leftblockertexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "floorbody")


    var removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()






    var txtField: UITextField = UITextField()
    txtField.frame = CGRectMake(50, 70, 200, 30)
    txtField.backgroundColor =  UIColor.grayColor()



    skyColor = SKColor(red: 113.0/255.0, green: 197.0/255.0, blue: 207.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    self.backgroundColor = skyColor

    buttoncolour = SKColor.blackColor()













    //floorbody.color = SKColor.lightGrayColor()
    floorbody = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundbody)
    floorbody.size.width = self.size.width
    floorbody.size.height = self.size.height / 2
    floorbody.zPosition = 8
    floorbody.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:self.frame.size.height / 7.7)
    self.addChild(floorbody)


    ground = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundimage)
    ground.zPosition = 9
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        ground.size.width = self.size.width/1.47
        ground.size.height = self.size.height / 18
    }else{
        ground.size.width = self.size.width/1.4
        ground.size.height = self.size.height / 16
    }
    ground.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:self.frame.size.height / 2.70)
    self.addChild(ground)


    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        dummy.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:self.frame.size.height / 2.80)
    }else{
        dummy.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:self.frame.size.height / 2.76)
    }





    dummy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, groundimage.size().height))
    dummy.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(dummy)

    title = SKSpriteNode(texture: titleimage)
    title.zPosition = 7
    title.size.width = self.size.width / 3
    title.size.height = self.size.height / 13.5
    title.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:self.frame.size.height / 1.17)
    self.addChild(title)

    //contactNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: leftblockertexture)
    contactNode.size.height = self.size.height / 3
    contactNode.size.width = self.size.width / 200
    contactNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) / 1.1)
    contactNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    contactNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: contactNode.size)
    contactNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    contactNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.ScoreCategory.rawValue
    contactNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.BigPersonCategory.rawValue
    contactNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.BigPersonCategory.rawValue
    self.addChild(contactNode)




    //leftblocker = SKSpriteNode(texture: leftblockertexture)
    leftblocker.zPosition = 9
    leftblocker.size.width = self.size.width / 20
    leftblocker.size.height = self.size.height / 5
    leftblocker.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) / 1.87, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    leftblocker.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    leftblocker.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: leftblocker.size)

    leftblocker.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.LeftCategory.rawValue
    leftblocker.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.BigPersonCategory.rawValue
    leftblocker.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.BigPersonCategory.rawValue

    self.addChild(leftblocker)

    //rightblocker = SKSpriteNode(texture: leftblockertexture)
    rightblocker.zPosition = 9
    rightblocker.size.width = self.size.width / 20
    rightblocker.size.height = self.size.height / 5
    rightblocker.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    rightblocker.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) * 1.46, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    rightblocker.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: rightblocker.size)
    rightblocker.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.RightCategory.rawValue
    rightblocker.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.BigPersonCategory.rawValue
    rightblocker.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.BigPersonCategory.rawValue


    self.addChild(rightblocker)





    playbutton = SKSpriteNode(texture: playbuttonimage)
    playbutton.zPosition = 7
    playbutton.size.width = self.size.width / 6
    playbutton.size.height = self.size.height / 7
    playbutton.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) / 1.25, y:self.frame.size.height / 0.5 )
    playbutton.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: playbutton.size.height / 2.0)
    playbutton.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    playbutton.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.addChild(playbutton)

    leaderboardbutton = SKSpriteNode(texture: leaderboardimage)
    leaderboardbutton.zPosition = 7
    leaderboardbutton.size.width = self.size.width / 6
    leaderboardbutton.size.height = self.size.height / 7
    leaderboardbutton.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) / 0.84, y:self.frame.size.height / 0.5 )
    leaderboardbutton.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: leaderboardbutton.size.height / 2.0)
    leaderboardbutton.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    leaderboardbutton.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.addChild(leaderboardbutton)


    ScoreSoundAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(ScoreSound, waitForCompletion: false)



}



enum BodyType:UInt32
{
case BigPersonCategory = 1
case SmallPersonCategory = 2
case ScoreCategory = 4
case LeftCategory = 8
case RightCategory = 16
}
```

**Here Is The Code For Spawning Them:**

```
        self.BigPerson.size.height = self.size.height / 9
        self.BigPerson.size.width = self.size.width / 13.45
        self.BigPerson.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) / 2 , self.frame.size.height / 2.2)


        self.BigPerson.zPosition = 10
        BigPerson.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: BigPerson.size)
        //BigPerson.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        BigPerson.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        BigPerson.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.BigPersonCategory.rawValue
        BigPerson.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        BigPerson.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.SmallPersonCategory.rawValue
        BigPerson.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.SmallPersonCategory.rawValue



        let MoveRight = SKAction.moveByX(self.size.width * 1.20, y: 0, duration: MoveTime)
        BigPerson.runAction(MoveRight)

        self.addChild(self.BigPerson)

        ChooseSide = 1

        //

        //self.SmallPerson = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "")
        //self.SmallPerson = SKSpriteNode(texture: SmallPersonTexture)
        self.SmallPerson.size.height = self.size.height / 14
        self.SmallPerson.size.width = self.size.width / 21

        self.SmallPerson.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) * 1.5, self.frame.size.height / 2.3)


        self.SmallPerson.zPosition = 9
        SmallPerson.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: SmallPerson.size)
        SmallPerson.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        SmallPerson.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        SmallPerson.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.SmallPersonCategory.rawValue
        SmallPerson.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        SmallPerson.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        SmallPerson.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.BigPersonCategory.rawValue


        SmallPerson.size.width = -SmallPerson.size.width
        self.addChild(self.SmallPerson)
```

**Here Is The Code For Detecting Collisions:**

```
        func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {





        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        let fadeAway = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.31)

        switch(contactMask)
        {
case BodyType.BigPersonCategory.rawValue | BodyType.SmallPersonCategory.rawValue:


            BigPerson.removeAllActions()
              StopGame()
     println("Test")


 default:
                 return
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `contactDelegate` to get contact detection call backs in the code. Also add `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` to the `SKScene`.

To add `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`

```
class GameScene : Scene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate
```

To add `contactDelegate`

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

Set the `dynamic` property to true for both bodies.

```
BigPerson.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
SmallPerson.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :)  I tried that but it does not seem to work still when the two of them collide.  Is there anything else I could possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: I added the didmovetoview code to my  question on this topic as it could not fit on the comments, sorry I took so long I could not figure out how to edit.  Thanks again!

Comment: I set the dynamics to true, but now it just has them run push each other, it is not telling me when they are contacting each other.  Am I doing contact detection properly?  I have it working for my big person with objects that are not moving, but now when I have 2 of them that are moving it does not work.  Does it not work for detecting more than 2 objects that are moving?

Comment: you have to set `collissionBitMask = 0` for both to not push each other.

Comment: I tried again and it is still unfortunately not doing anything when I set it to all the previous codes.  They just run past eachother with no detection in the coding.

Comment: i don't understand the problem. i may have to look at your complete code to know.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate your time, how should I send you the code of it?Thanks

Comment: in your code, you are setting `SmallPerson.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask` before initialising the `SmallPerson.physicsBody`. This will not work. Put the code after you initialise physicsBody. Also set dynamic to true. And Remove the `contactNode`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That has fixed it, I never realized that the order was completely off of it, I spent so long looking for the error!